# Is it possible to use the load API in jQuery to load fragments with a class selector rather than an id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to edit a dashboard for a site by adding more widgets to the page. The widgets that I'm trying to add already exist on another page in the same domain.
I found out I could use the load API in jQuery to basically copy them there.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
//Result is content from the entire page at test.html
```

Even better I can load specific page fragments with an addition to the parameter.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
//Result is content only from the page where the id is "container" specifically
```

My question is, is there a way I can use a class selector instead of an id selector to grab content.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html .fancy-container" );
```

Something like that.

Comment: Yes. The selector can be any valid selector string.

Comment: Did you tried it?

Comment: Yes, it didn't work. I'll check my syntax though

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes any selector will work in that area.

This was answered in the comments and not by me.